# react-google-maps api onRightclick event not working on Macbook touchpad

Tags: react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I just started using React Google Maps API https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#marker, and I noticed that the `onRightClick` props or event is not fired when using Macbook trackpad on browsers that use Webkit specifically (Chrome, Opera, Safari). I noticed this issue in the `Marker` component https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#marker and `GoogleMap` component https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#googlemap. Please, did you face a similar problem? If yes, how did you solve it?